# How to get the response object size?

Tags: java, json, servlets

In Spring framework, I am using  `HttpServletResponse` response object , then I have set content type as *JSON*.

Now I want to print the size of the response object in `log.info()`.

In Postman I am successfully getting the response in *JSON* format. 
All I need is to print the size in bytes in spring boot app console page when I run the app as Spring Boot application.

Comment: you can convert the JSON to string and use getBytes to convert it to byte[] and take it length. This will give you only rough idea of memory utilization for the Object. I have tried instrumentation api for getting the size of Object. But it gave same 24 bytes for any length string I gave.

Comment: @SujayMohan I guess my answer would help you out too. There's already an API for it in-built.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the following in your test script:

```
console.log(pm.response.size());
```

This will log an object which has the properties that will give you the size in bytes for the header, the body and also the total size.

Additionally,  you can directly view the detailed response size by hovering over the `Size` text in the UI

[image: response size]

Comment: I can see the size in postman , but that's not my requirement. I need to print on the console page when I run the application as spring boot app.